# How can I search for a value that starting with a specific number in a column of a dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, string, dataframe, data-cleaning

I have a DataFrame like this

```
example = {'x': [121,'201-208-209','300A',320,'100A'], 'y': ['a','b','c','d','e']}
df = pd.DataFrame(example)
```

I want to know which values are starting with a specific number. I want to know this because this way I can better categorize my database. For example, if I know that there is a row that the value of the columns "x" start with 1 I will aggregate a column with "Floor 1" in the same row, but if this value start with 2 it will be "Floor 2" and so on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Would 'startswith' work ?

```
df['x'].str.startswith('1')
```

Comment: Hi @Daniel Weigel , it wotks but only with the data that is string, with the  data that the type is int, it didn't work.

Comment: In that case, you can make sure to convert your series to a string prior to evaluating the condition: df['x'].astype(str).str.startswith("1")

Comment: Yes, you are right but with `df['x'].astype(str).str.startswith("1")` it dind't work. I used `str(df[i]).startswith('1')`, and I put it in a loop for each row, this way all the numbers is convert to strings. Thanks for your help